# Scala cipher AES decryption does not work -- conditionally unable to decrypt file -- padding error

Tags: scala, encryption, error-handling, aes, padding

Scala 2.11.8, help with encryption...  This follows principles from [this stackoverflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466951/unable-to-decrypt-a-file-using-cipher-class) and gives an error (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded).  I know why the error is caused, but, need help in handling it.  **Note: error occurs when the decrypt code is executed separately (i.e. on a different window, separate spark-shell instance).**  Rarely, the error occurs when both encrypt and decrypt are in the same instance... The salt and IvSpec are copied to the separate instance --as shown at the end (Note: I have verified that the bytes are the same in both instances)...

```
import java.io.{BufferedWriter, File, FileWriter, FileInputStream, FileOutputStream, BufferedInputStream, BufferedOutputStream, DataInputStream, DataOutputStream}
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import javax.crypto.{Cipher, SecretKey, SecretKeyFactory, CipherInputStream, CipherOutputStream}
import javax.crypto.spec.{IvParameterSpec, SecretKeySpec, PBEKeySpec}
import java.security.SecureRandom
import scala.util.Random
import scala.math.pow

val password = "Let us test this" 

val random = new SecureRandom();
val salt = Array.fill[Byte](16)(0)
random.nextBytes(salt)

val IvSpec1 = Array.fill[Byte](16)(0)
random.nextBytes(IvSpec1)
val IvSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IvSpec1)

def password_to_key(password: String, salt: Array[Byte]): SecretKeySpec = {
    val spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
    val f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    val key = f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded()
    new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES")
}

val Key = password_to_key(password, salt)

val Algorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"
val cipher_encrypt = Cipher.getInstance(Algorithm)
cipher_encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, Key, IvSpec)
val cipher_decrypt = Cipher.getInstance(Algorithm)
cipher_decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, Key, IvSpec)

def encrypt(file_in: String, file_out: String, cipher_encrypt:javax.crypto.Cipher )  {
    val in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file_in))
    val out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file_out))
    val out_encrypted = new CipherOutputStream(out, cipher_encrypt)

    val bufferSize = 1024 * pow(2,4).toInt
    val bb = new Array[Byte](bufferSize)
    var bb_read = in.read(bb, 0, bufferSize)
    while (bb_read > 0) {
        out_encrypted.write(bb, 0, bb_read)
        bb_read = in.read(bb, 0, bufferSize)
    }
    in.close()
    out_encrypted.close()
    out.close()
}

def decrypt(file_in: String, file_out: String, cipher_decrypt:javax.crypto.Cipher )  {
    val in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file_in))
    val in_decrypted = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher_decrypt)

    val out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file_out))
    val bufferSize = 1024 * pow(2,4).toInt
    val bb = new Array[Byte](bufferSize)
    var bb_read = in_decrypted.read(bb, 0, bufferSize)
    while (bb_read >0 )  {
        out.write(bb, 0, bb_read)
        bb_read = in_decrypted.read(bb, 0, bufferSize)
    } 
    in_decrypted.close()
    in.close()
    out.close()
} 

val file_in = "test.csv"
val file_encrypt = "test_encrypt.csv"
val file_decrypt = "test_decrypt.csv"
encrypt(file_in, file_encrypt, cipher_encrypt)
decrypt( file_encrypt, file_decrypt, cipher_decrypt)

// To write salt, IvSpec (to re-read it in a separate instance...)
val salt_loc = new File("salt.txt")
val IvSpec_loc = new File("IvSpec.txt")
val salt_w = new FileOutputStream(salt_loc)
salt_w.write(salt)
salt_w.close()
val IvSpec_w = new FileOutputStream(IvSpec_loc)
IvSpec_w.write(IvSpec1)
IvSpec_w.close()

//to re-read salt and IvSpec in a separate instance...
//Ignore that we do not need to re-read IvSpec 
val salt_loc = new File("salt.txt")
val IvSpec_loc = new File("IvSpec.txt")
val salt_r = new FileInputStream(salt_loc)
val salt = Stream.continually(salt_r.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
val IvSpec_r = new FileInputStream(IvSpec_loc)
val IvSpec1 = Stream.continually(IvSpec_r.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).map(_.toByte).toArray
val IvSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IvSpec1)
```

When the decrypt code is executed in a separate java process, this definitely gives an error (error is related to padding).  This works most times (95%+), when encrypt and decrypt are done in the same script (e.g. above will work most of the time - if executed in the same instance). If decrypt is done separately, by getting the salt and IvSpec in a separate window/process/thread/java instance, it fails.

```
error is java.io.IOException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
  at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:121)
  at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:239)
  at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:215)
  at decrypt3(<console>:81)
  ... 60 elided
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:991)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2047)
  at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:118)
  ... 63 more
```

Comment: are there any particular strings that work more or less reliably than others?

Comment: nothing in particular that I noticed... --these were just a bunch of csv files with alphanumeric values.

Comment: `error is related to padding` you will get this exception when having wrong IV or key, as the decrypted value results into invalid padding. Note: having zero IV is really not secure option

Comment: I'd say different instances are using different (random) salt resulting into different key (try to debug and print used salt, iv amd key)

Comment: Printing out salt (and Ivspec separately) confirms that these are the same bytes that I am using for encryption and decryption...  If they are different, it would not work at all in the same instance -- where it works (but fails randomly in about 6% of cases)